# Why is synchronously listening to a subprocess “after” spawning it considered safe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const subprocess = require("child_process").spawn("bad_command");
subprocess.on("error", _ => {
    console.info("Failed to spawn a subprocess.");
});
```

```
> node test.js
Failed to spawn a subprocess.
```

> Construct one, *and then* listen to it.

While this is considered as the right way to listen to *listenables*<sup>(`socket.io` sockets do it, too.)</sup> in Node.js (or perhaps Javascript) and I know it would work with no problems, still, I have a slight doubt in my mind: “**for what reason does it *never* miss any events out?**”

---

My understanding was that events may *asynchronously* happen at *any time from the creation* of the emitter. So I thought like “Why not happening *before* listening (`.on`) to them? *What* exactly ensures that there won’t be any events happening before listening, before calling the `.on` method?”

Having two more experiments,

```
const subprocess = require("child_process").spawn("bad_command");
setTimeout(_ => subprocess.on("error", _ => {
    console.info("Failed to spawn a subprocess.");
}), 10);
```

```
> node test.js
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn bad_command ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn bad_command',
  path: 'bad_command',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

```
const subprocess = require("child_process").spawn("bad_command");
(function heavy_synchronous_task_that_takes_much_longer() {
    const Crypto = require("crypto");
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1_000_000);
    console.log(Date.now());
    for(let i = 0; i < 10_000; ++i) {
        Crypto.randomFillSync(buffer);
    }
    console.log(Date.now());
})();
subprocess.on("error", _ => {
    console.info("Failed to spawn a subprocess.");
});
```

```
> node test.js
1562646732809
1562646744631
Failed to spawn a subprocess.
```

I found there *is* something that ensures it, only if listener-attaching is synchronous (Timing doesn’t matter I guess.), but I cannot grasp what’s going on under the hood because the code itself does not tell me anything about the why.

I believe one can give me a good language-specification–wise, or engine-implementation–wise explanation.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30906228/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48794320/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

The error event is emitted on process exit, which is handled by the "nextTick" function (see line 1140 [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/child_process.js)).

The nextTick, if I'm reading the [event loop documentation](https://nodejs.org/fa/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) correctly, allows us to "by using process.nextTick() we guarantee that [...] always runs its callback after the rest of the user's code and before the event loop is allowed to proceed."